# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos x\times \exp\left [ \frac{a}{\cos x}\right]\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos x\times \exp\left [ \frac{a}{\cos x}\right]\,dx$$

where $a$ is complex parameter. (**Integral does not converge if $a$ is Real**)

I tried to solve it by two methods.

1. The first is direct replacement $z=e^{ix}$. After that the integral goes to $$-\frac{i}{2}\oint_{\left| z \right| < 1}\frac{1+z^2}{z^2}\exp{\left[\frac{2az}{z^2+1}\right]}\,dz$$
2. Before switching to complex numbers, you can use substitution $t=1/\cos x$ to reduce this integral to the form: $$2\int_{0}^{+\infty }\frac{e^{at}}{t^2\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$$
   And after that we can go to complex plane.

But because of the complex contours, integrating in both cases is a difficult task for me.

Comment: Are you sure convergence is compatible with $a$ being any real non-complex number? I think you actually want $a$ to be imaginary. (In particular, the integral converges to $0$ if $a=0$.)

Comment: If `a` is only imaginary then:$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \text{sgn}(a) \left(a^2 (\pi  \pmb{L}_1(a)+2) I_0(a)+2 \sqrt{-a^2}-a (\pi  a \pmb{L}_0(a)+2) I_1(a)\right)$$ with CAS.Mathematica code:`\[Pi]/2 Sign[
  a] (2 Sqrt[-a^2] - a BesselI[1, a] (2 + a \[Pi] StruveL[0, a]) + 
   a^2 BesselI[0, a] (2 + \[Pi] StruveL[1, a]))`

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, the integral converges only if $a$ is purely imaginary (otherwise zeros of $\cos x$ represent non-integrable singularities). The substitution $t=1/\cos x$, done *carefully*, leads to $$f(a)=2\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{at}-e^{-at}}{t^2\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt,$$ with $f''(i\lambda)=2\pi i J_0(\lambda)$ for $\lambda>0$, according to [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#E12) integral for the Bessel function.

This may give a way to confirm (or refute) the CAS result given in comments.

Comment: Wow. It is really great. Thank you very much!!!